# Uninitialised array using malloc()

Tags: c, arrays

**It was, actually, the display function after all. Sorry if I wasted your time (I didn't actually put the code of the display function here, my bad. However, I did learn some new things, so thank you all!**

I have created a structure which involves an array that represents a set of integers.
When I first create a structure, I use malloc() to allocate space for the structure and thus, the array.

The problem resides, however, in the fact that when I create the structure, the first element of the array is being assigned a number. I want, however, to just create a structure where the array in it is uninitialised.

```
typedef struct set{
    int numberOfValues; /* The number of values in the set */
    int value[40]; /* the set */
} *Set; /* Set is thus a pointer to struct set */

Set aOfPStructs[4];

void create()
{
    static int setnum = 0;

    Set S; /* S is a pointer to struct set */


    if (setnum <= 4)
    {
        S = (struct set *) malloc(sizeof(struct set));
        S->numberOfValues = 0;

        aOfPStructs[setnum] = S;

        printf("The set's number is %d\n", setnum);
        setnum++;
    }
    else
        printf("Error. No more sets can be created.\n");
}
```

The above is only a snippet from the whole program, but any other code is irrelevant to the question tbh.

So with that code, if I were to display the contents of the array in the structure, I would get 1 value. Thing is, I have not added any elements to the array, so I should get no values at this point. Can I fix this?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Edit:
I tried memset(), but it's not exactly what I want. When I use the create(), I want 0 elements in the array value[], but the code is generating 1 random element once I use the create function.

The function. to display the element seems to work just fine though. Funny thing is, when I run a function to delete one element from the array, that extra element is removed, only to be added again if I run the add() function.

Edit 2:
Added a screenshot for further explanation of my problem. I appreciate every comment thus far, and future ones too.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OimZ.jpg

Edit 3:
Ok, I get the use of memset() now and the concept of initialisation. Thing is, if I wanted to check the number of elements of the set, just right after I create it, I should get 0 because I have not added any elements,  but an element is being generated with create...

Comment: I don't see the place in the code where "if I were to display the contents of the array in the structure, I would get 1 value". Where does that happen?

Comment: Please remember that most C compilers doesn't guarantee variables to be zeroed.

Comment: never cast the result of malloc()

Comment: If I create a set, and display the contents using a display function I created, right after the creation of the set, it shows me that the first element of the array is initialised to a random number.

I don'd want that, I'd like to have an empty array when I have just created the set.

Comment: memset() the struct with zeroes

Comment: Unrelated: I'm going to mention something you probably won't enjoy hearing, but its none-the-less true: **Don't hide pointer types in typedefs *unless* it is purposely done for an API handle-like abstraction**. C programmers *want* to see the asterisks. Really. Not kidding. They call out to the program reviewer saying "See here? this is a pointer. It holds an address." When it comes to pointers, the more they're *exposed* for what they are (pointers) the less likely they are to be used erroneously.

Comment: who teached you to use "uppercase - single Letter" Variable names?

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig, I just wrote an answer without realizing that "Set S" is really a pointer and not a complete structure.

Comment: @PeterMiehle *exactly*.

Comment: Btw, this: `setnum <= 4` should be `setnum < 4` in your `create` function. You have an array of 4 items, thus indexable only from `0...3` .

Comment: @WhozCraig, Oh OK, I'll work on that, never knew about it.

Comment: If you want everything zeroed use calloc. If you can't (because it is an assignement), clear the memory with `memset(S, 0, sizeof(*S))`

Comment: @PeterMiehle, Bad habit, I'll fix that.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Basically, if the user of the type is ever expected to dererefence it (either explicitly with `*` or implicitly with `->` or `[]`), then the type's pointer-ness should be fully exposed.

Comment: After your update, and my last comment, I think you're indexing your arrays out-of-bounds. C arrays are 0-indexed through (N-1), where N is the array magnitude. For an array of 40 elements, that means your can index from 0...39. Your posted code already shows one place where you are exceeding your array magnitude and therefore entering **undefined behavior**, and I'm betting your doing the same for your sub-array dumping as well.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem — and include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself.  As OP noted: "It was, actually, the display function after all. … I didn't actually put the code of the display function here."

Answer (score 2):

I think you may not understand what "initialized" and "uninitialized" mean.

"Uninitialized" means "holding whatever bit pattern happens to be left over from the last computation that used this memory or from bootstrapping the machine."

"Initialized" just means you have assigned a set value.

The `malloc` call gives you uninitialized storage according to this definition.  So what you are seeing is the best you can get.  You are printing the integer formed from the arbitrary bit pattern in the first array slot.

For what it's worth, the simplest way to get a pre-zeroed memory block of `n` `int`s (initialized to zero) is to say.

```
int *blk = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: you may want `calloc(n, sizeof(int))` as it deals with alignment issues and large allocation better.

Comment: @chux Thanks.  This is a fair point, but I'm curious about which runtime system implements `calloc(n, m)` with code other than `malloc(n * m)` (followed by a `memset`). I have looked at quite a few C runtime libs and never seen one that didn't.  The C Standard certainly doesn't call for alignment of arrays different from that for a single element.  If you do the multiplication (in this case by 4 or 8) in the calloc call, the compiler can optimize it away.  With your suggested change (which I made), it can't.

Comment: Example: DOS large/huge memory model the product of n*m overflows, both `n`, `m` and `size_t` being the `sizeof(uint16_t)`, but `calloc(n,m)` works.  I'm sure there are more - likely an esoteric OS. /// "C Standard ... alignment ... single element" is true, but by passing `(1,n*m)` vs. `(n,m)`, the size of a single element increases to `n*m` maybe restricting candidate buffers that may be returned with a single element size of `m`.  BTW: my cadet made it back to WP on time (even going via Detroit).

Comment: Yikes DOS large/huge. I have not thought of that for 15 years. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`memset`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/memset/) to set to `0` all the data in the structure. By default when you use `malloc` the memory you get is not initiliazed:

```
S = (struct set *) malloc(sizeof(struct set));
memset(S, 0, sizeof(struct set));
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the function displaying your set. I suppose that the problem may be there. Maybe you use something like `for(i=0; i <= S->numberOfValues; i++)` instead of `for(i=0; i < S->numberOfValues; i++)`, so you print the first element even if not there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It uses a little different approach to create and initialize array of structs, but the relevant point is that it uses memset to init array of ints for each element of struct array:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int numberOfValues; /* The number of values in the set */
    int value[40]; /* the set */
}SET;

SET  set[4], *pSet; //initialize SET *, pSet to the first position of set

main() 
{
    int i;
    pSet= &set[0];
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        memset(pSet[i].value, 0, sizeof(int)*40); //set all elements of member value to 0   
    }

}
```